Mocking a class with arguments, but getting NameError: name 'my_position' is not defined
I am trying to mock out a class that is being called/initialised in a function.
def example_function():
    example_class = SomeClass(my_position, num_list, suit_list)


@mock.patch('.../SomeClass')
def test_example_function(mock_SomeClass):
    example_function()

When I run the above, I get:
NameError: name 'my_position' is not defined

However, I know that SomeClass is being mocked out, because if I set a breakpoint() in the line just above example_class = SomeClass(my_position, num_list, suit_list)
And print out SomeClass it says:
<MagicMock name='ShouldWePlayThisPreFlopHand' id='139711184614096'>

Any ideas how I can overcome this?
Some additional information: I am defining my_position as a global variable within the python package of example_function().
So when I run a unit test, my_position is not initialised/set.

I think it's just that, as the my_position variable is not initialised/set/imported when running the example_function function, Python is telling you that the variable needs to exist before using it. If the variable is global as part of the package, you would need to import it in order to use it.

So there's no way of mocking out SomeClass completely so it doesn't even make the call to the class? That is really what I'm after

The problem is not the 'call to the class'. Python evaluates the variables you are sending to the class' constructor before actually calling the constructor. So, if Python detects that one of the variables does not exist, it will raise an error before instantiating the class. If you define the my_position, num_list and suit_list variables, it should be fine.

@killerbee88 Could you add more files code? Show the name and contents of the file where are defined example_function(), the class SomeClass, the global variables my_position, num_list, suit_list... The patch instruction is exactly patch('.../SomeClass')? or is it patch('__main__.SomeClass')? Please clarify your question!
